# Django REST API query on related field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have 3 models, Run, RunParameter, RunValue:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

class RunParameter(models.Model):
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class RunValue(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    run_parameter = models.ForeignKey(RunParameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)

    class Meta:
            unique_together=(('run','run_parameter'),)
```

A **Run** can have a **RunValue**, which is a float value with the value's name coming from **RunParameter** (which is basically a table containing names), for example:

A **RunValue** could be **AverageTime**, or **MaximumTemperature**

A **Run** could then have **RunValue = RunParameter:AverageTime** with value X.

Another **Run** instance could have **RunValue = RunParameter:MaximumTemperature** with value Y, etc.

I created an endpoint to query my API, but I only have the **RunParameter** ID (because of the way you can select which parameter you want to graph), not the **RunValue** ID directly. I basically show a list of all **RunParameter** and a list of all **Run** instances, because if I showed all instances of **RunValue** the list would be too long and confusing, as instead of seeing "Maximum Temperature" you would see:

- "Maximum Temperature for Run X"
- "Maximum Temperature for Run Y"
- "Maximum Temperature for Run Z", etc. (repeat 50+ times).

My API view looks like this:

```
class RunValuesDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = RunValue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RunValuesDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]]
```

And the serializer for that looks like this:

```
class RunValuesDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    run = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = RunValue
        fields = [
            'id',
            'run',
            'run_parameter',
            'value'
        ]
    def get_run(self, obj):
        return str(obj.run)
```

And the URL just in case it's relevant:

```
url(r'^run-values/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RunValuesDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='values_list_detail'),
```

Since I'm new to REST API, so far I've only dealt with having the ID of the model API view I am querying directly, but never an ID of a related field. I'm not sure where to modify my queryset to pass it an ID to get the appropriate model instance from a related field.

At the point I make the API query, I have the **Run** instance ID and the **RunParameter** ID. I would need the queryset to be:

```
run_value = RunValue.objects.get(run=run_id, run_parameter_id=param_id)
```

While so far I've only ever had to do something like:

```
run_value = RunValue.objects.get(id=value_id) # I don't have this ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its pretty simple, all you have to do is override the `get_object` method, for example(copy pasted from [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins)):

```
# view
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class RunValuesDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = RunValue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RunValuesDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]]
    lookup_fields = ["run_id", "run_parameter_id"]

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

# url
url(r'^run-values/(?P<run_id>\d+)/(?P<run_parameter_id>\d+)/$', RunValuesDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='values_list_detail'),
```

But one big thing you need to be careful, is **not** to have duplicate entries with same `run_id` and `run_parameter_id`, then it will throw errors. To avoid it, either use [**`unique_together=['run', 'run_parameter']`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) or you can use [**`queryset.filter(**filter).first()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) instead of `get_object_or_404` in the view. But second option will produce wrong results when duplicate entries are created.

Comment: The object models do have a unique together constraint, I didn't include it to save space, but now that you mention it, it is relevant and I'll edit the original post to include them, as not to confuse others who may find the answer later on. I'll try this solution and update here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your answer helped, but how could I adapt this to take in multiple RunParameter IDs? Say if I queried my api as: `/api/run-values/?run=1&run_parameter=29,30,31,32,33` ?

Comment: Probably you are looking for filtering: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get an instance of `RunValue` with only the `Run` id and the `RunParameter` id, i.e. query based on related fields.

The queryset can be achieved with the following:

```
run_value = RunValue.objects.get(
                          run__id=run_id,
                          run_parameter__id=run_parameter_id
            )
```

Providing that a `RunValue` instance only ever has 1 related `Run` and `RunParameter`, this will return the instance of `RunValue` you're after.

Let me know if that's not what you mean.

The double underscore allows you to access those related instance fields in your query.